# add border-bottom to nested list items

Tags: html, css

I want to add a bottom border to every list item with css. Here is my CSS code:

```
ul,ol{
    li{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        padding-top: 3px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;

        ul,ol{
            margin-left: 2em;
                li{
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

It gives an output like this:

Screenshot url: http://oi34.tinypic.com/ih1eea.jpg

The css code is working fine on top level item. But not on the sublists. Please see the screenshot and help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: better post your code

Comment: @Sowmya Sorry? I couldn't understand that what do you mean?

Comment: I meant full code. HTML also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8mJUj/)

Give a class to your `ul` say `demo`

```
.demo li {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;  
}
```

If you want each and every li in your website should get `border-bottom` which won't be a great idea than use

```
ul li {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

If you want to indent your nested `li` you can use text

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you have posted in the question is wrong. (*you cannot do nesting in CSS rules*)

The equivalent correct syntax is

```
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

 li ul, 
 li ol{
    margin-left: 2em;
}
```

Comment: same problem. The borders of sub list items showing at the bottom of top level ul. like the screenshot

Comment: @DON, do you want when a `li` has sub-items (*a nested `ul` or `ol`*) to **not** show its own `border-bottom` ?

Comment: And can you post an image of how you want it to appear ?

Comment: I want to show a border-bottom under every list item. nested and top level list items

Comment: @Don my code show exactly what is in your pic. See http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/8mJUj/1/

Comment: You code also have the same problem. As you can see in the screenshot: http://oi36.tinypic.com/zlviub.jpg

Comment: @Don please post an image of ***how you want it to look!***, not how the problem is..

Answer (score -2):

i'm not sure i understund you very well, but there is simple code for You:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <ul class="list-1">
        <li class="item-1">Item 1
            <ul class="list-1-1">
                <li>Item 1-1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.list-1 li.item-1, ol.list-1 li.item-1 {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        padding-top: 3px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;   
}
ul.list-1 li.item-1 ul.list-1-1 , ol.list-1 li.item-1 ul.list-1-1 {
    margin-left: 2em;
}
ul.list-1-1 li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/jVcFb/1/

Comment: You have the same problem in your demo